# Centered cells with tabularx and linebreak

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, tabularx

I would like to have centered cells **and** have manual linebreaks within tabularx. I searched a lot in stackexchange and other latex related pages, but cannot find a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage[]{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[]{array}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{lX|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}}
        & & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Target1}} &  &  &  \\
        & {\footnotesize rot\par} & test123 \newline hallo &  {\footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \newline testtext\par} &  {\footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \newline hardware\par} \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Why is the first line of each cell not center aligned? If I have no linebreak within the cell the first line is correctly aligned. How to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Edit:
I compiled the code with overleaf and some other online latex environments to ensure my environment is not fishy
[image]

Comment: Which cell which you'd like to have centred, is not?

Comment: Third, fourth and fith. Bascially all cells which are in the "P" column.

Comment: When I tested the code; they were all centred.

Comment: I think you need to replace `\newline` with `\par` inside the `p` cells, because centering is only properly aligned after a `\par`.

Comment: I added a picture to the post, so you see the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why this does not work as expected is rooted in the fact that `\centering` only works correctly [if the relevant text ends with a `\par`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/23653/47927).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}  
\begin{document}  

\parbox{5cm}{%
\centering This is a line \newline
And this is another line %
}

\parbox{5cm}{%
\centering This is a line \par
And this is another line % (implicit \par at the end of the \parbox)
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same is true if you use `\centering` inside a `p` column, since this essentially places a `\parbox` inside the table cell. So instead of using `\newline` inside these cells, you should use `\par` (or enter a blank line):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{lX|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}}
        & & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Target1}} &  &  &  \\
        & \footnotesize rot & test123 \par hallo & \footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \par testtext & \footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \par hardware \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I removed all packages from the code that are not necessary for this example and simplified the code a bit.

Answer (score 6):

You asked,

> Why is the first line of each cell not center aligned? ... How to solve this?

I'm afraid I cannot tell you *why* the problem you've encountered arises, but I can propose a solution: Load the `ragged2e` package, which provides a macro called `\Centering`, and replace

```
>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}
```

with

```
>{\Centering}p{#1}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
%% 2 ways to create a centered "p"-type column:
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{Q}[1]{>{\Centering}p{#1}}

\usepackage[skip=0.333\baselineskip]{caption} % optional

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \caption*{with \ttfamily >\{\string\centering\string\arraybackslash\}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X *{3}{| P{0.2\linewidth}} }
        & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\ 
        \hline
        Target1 
        & test123 \newline hallo 
        & \footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \newline testtext 
        & \footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \newline hardware \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    
\begin{table}[h]
    \caption*{with \ttfamily >\{\string\Centering\}}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ X *{3}{| Q{0.2\linewidth}} }
        & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\
        \hline
        Target1
        & test123 \newline hallo
        & \footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \newline testtext
        & \footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \newline hardware \\
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had no centring problem with your code, but I propose a simpilfication of your code if you have a recent version of `array`, which defines a `wc{some length}` column type. Also needless to load `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` nowadays, since this is the encoding that latex expects by default now.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage[]{multirow}
    \usepackage[]{MnSymbol}
    \usepackage[]{array}
    \usepackage{multicol}

    \begin{document}

    %\maketitle

    \section{Introduction}

    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{l>{\centering\arraybackslash}X|wc{0.2\linewidth}|wc{0.2\linewidth}|wc{0.2\linewidth}|}
            & & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\
            \multicolumn{2}{l|}{\textbf{Target1}} & & & \\
            & {\footnotesize rot\par} & test123 \newline hallo & {\footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \newline testtext\par} & {\footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \newline hardware\par} \\
            \hline
            \hline
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As far as I understood the question, the problem was regarding the alignment when a `\newline` is placed. Your code seems to ignore this.

Comment: @JasperHabicht: I just copy-pasted the code in the question,  and modified what  I mentioned to simplify the code`. But you're right,I'll see whether \newline works. with this code