# vertical alignment with multicolumn and multiline cell content

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have a problem regarding the same file like described here:
[Centered cells with tabularx and linebreak](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/652971/centered-cells-with-tabularx-and-linebreak/652984#652984)
Using that Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage[]{MnSymbol}
\usepackage[]{array}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tabularx}{1\linewidth}{lX|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}|P{0.2\linewidth}}
        & & \textbf{firmware} & \textbf{bootloader} & \textbf{os} \\
        \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Target1}} &  &  &  \\
        & {\footnotesize rot\par} & test123 \newline hallo &  {\footnotesize $(\uparrow)$ \newline testtext\par} &  {\footnotesize $(\nearrow)$ \newline hardware\par} \\
        \hline
        \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Will result in
[image]

Is there anyway to align the first cell with in the mid of the other cells? Regardless if there are two, three, one or four lines in the cells?

Comment: Define ˛column tapy `P` as `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{table}`, however, your table is a bit unusual ...

Answer (score 0):

Something like this below?

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
% \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}


\begin{document}
\section{Introduction}
\begin{table}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}%
    \setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
    \centering%
    \footnotesize%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{
            C|
            P{0.2\linewidth}|
            P{0.2\linewidth}|
            P{0.2\linewidth}
        }
        \thead{Target1}
            & \thead{firmware}
            & \thead{bootloader}
            & \thead{os} \\
        rot
            & \makecell[cc]{$(\uparrow)$ test123\\hallo}
            & $(\uparrow)$ testtext
            & $(\nearrow)$ hardware \\
        \hline\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```