# Removing extra space from table with multirow and multicolumn

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow

I am getting extra space in the first three rows which I do not want. How to remove this extra space?

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{l c c c c c c c}    
    \hline \hline
    \multicolumn{8}{l}{}   \\ 
    Cases &  Left & Right & Below & Above & Numbers & Sum & Framework        \\
    \hline\hline
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{}   \\                             Case I       & \ding{55}& \checkmark& 0/$\pi$& 0  &0  & 0.1408-0.1496 & 0.057-0.059                   \\
        \hline
        \multicolumn{8}{l}{}    \\                           Case II  & \ding{55} & \checkmark& 0/$\pi$ &0-2$\pi$ & 0 & 0.1408-0.1496& 0.019-0.054                \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Case III} & \multirow{2}{*}{\checkmark} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ding{55}} & 0-0.78 & \multirow{2}{*}{-2.362$-$1.26} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.61-1.20} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.0773-0.1231} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.0059-0.026} \\ 
        &                   &                   & 3.14-3.66 &                   &                   &                   &                  \\ \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Case IV} & \multirow{2}{*}{\checkmark} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ding{55}} &0-0.78  & \multirow{2}{*}{0.60-1.84} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.61-1.20} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.0773-0.1231} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.013-0.025} \\
        &                   &                   & 3.14-3.66 &                   &                   &                   &                   \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{General Case} & \multirow{2}{*}{\checkmark} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ding{55}} &-1.5-0.6  & \multirow{2}{*}{-3-3} & \multirow{2}{*}{-2.85-1.13} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.06-1.12} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.001-0.03} \\
        &                   &                   & 1.38-1.57 &                   &                   &                   &                   \\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{General Case} & \multirow{2}{*}{\ding{55}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\checkmark} & -1.5-0.6 & \multirow{2}{*}{-3-3} &    -1.5$-$0.01               & \multirow{2}{*}{0.115-0.15} & \multirow{2}{*}{0.016-0.06} \\
        &                   &                   & 0.8-1.56 &                   &                   1.33-1.7&                   &             \\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Summary of the analysis.}\label{tab:summary}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image: Image attached]

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: The extra space is caused by the completely blank rows introduced by `\multicolumn{8}{l}{}   \\ ` but that's just one problem of many. Why are you using `\multirow` in almost every cell rather than just allowing the cells in the fourth column to break? Why aren't you using endashes for number ranges, and minus signs for negative numbers rather than using hyphens everywhere? There are many ways to improve that table.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to latex. Trying to improve.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show you a solution with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]\small\centering% see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering?rq=1
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lcc*5{rcl}},
    cell{2-Z}{4-Z}={mode=math},
    cell{1}{5,8,11,14,17}={cmd=\makebox[0pt]},
    cell{2}{5,8,11}={cmd=\makebox[0pt]},
    cell{3}{5,11}={cmd=\makebox[0pt]},
    cell{4-Z}{5}={preto=\text{--}},
    cell{3,4,6,8,10}{8}={preto=\text{--}},
    cell{4,6,8,10,11}{11}={preto=\text{--}},
    cell{2-4,6,8,10}{14,17}={preto=\text{--}},
    cell{4,6,8,10}{1}={r=2}{l},
    cell{4,6,8,10}{7,13,16}={r=2}{r},
    cell{4,6,8,10}{2,3,8,14,17}={r=2}{c},
    cell{4,6,8,10}{9,15,18}={r=2}{l},
    cell{4,6,8}{10}={r=2}{r},
    cell{4,6,8}{11}={r=2}{c},
    cell{4,6,8}{12}={r=2}{l},
    hline{1,2} = {1}{-}{},
    hline{1,2} = {2}{-}{},
    hline{3,4,6,8,10,12} = {}{-}{},
    colsep=5pt,
    column{4,7,10,13,16}={rightsep=1pt},
    column{5,8,11,14,17}={colsep=0pt},
    column{6,9,12,15,18}={leftsep=1pt},
    }    
    Cases &  Left & Right && Below &&& Above &&& Numbers &&& Sum &&& Framework & \\
    Case I & \ding{55}& \checkmark&& $0/\pi$&&& $0$ &&&$0$ && 0.1408&&0.1496 & 0.057&&0.059 \\
    Case II  & \ding{55} & \checkmark&& $0/\pi$ && 0&&2\pi && $0$&& 0.1408&&0.1496 & 0.019&&0.054 \\
    Case III & \checkmark & \ding{55} & 0&&0.78 & -2.362&&1.26 & 0.61&&1.20 & 0.0773&&0.1231 & 0.0059&&0.026 \\ 
    & & & 3.14&&3.66 & & & & &&&&&&&&\\ 
    Case IV & \checkmark & \ding{55} & 0&&0.78 & 0.60&&1.84 & 0.61&&1.20 & 0.0773&&0.1231 & 0.013&&0.025 \\
    & & & 3.14&&3.66 & & & & &&&&&&&&\\
    General Case & \checkmark & \ding{55} & -1.5&&0.6 & -3&&3 & -2.85&&1.13 & 0.06&&1.12 & 0.001&&0.03 \\
    & & & 1.38&&1.57 & & & & &&&&&&&&\\
    General Case & \ding{55} & \checkmark & -1.5&&0.6 & -3&&3 & -1.5&&0.01 & 0.115&&0.15 & 0.016&&0.06 \\
    & & & 0.8 &&1.56 & &&& 1.33 && 1.7 &&&&&&\\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Summary of the analysis.}\label{tab:summary}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]