# Replicating MS Word Table Style

Tags: tables, color

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'cp1252'-Western, 'cp1251'-Cyrillic, etc.
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{center}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \rowcolors{2}{lightgray!30}{}
    \begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{>{\centering \columncolor{lightgray}}m{2.4cm}|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X} \hline
    \rowcolor{lightgray}
\textbf{Unit Power (MW)} & \textbf{PSO} & \textbf{MFO} & \textbf{GA} \\ \hline\hline 
\textbf{P1} & 445.89 & 426.09 & 474.81 \\ \hline 
\textbf{P2} & 175.88 & 199.8 & 178.64 \\ \hline 
\textbf{P3} & 258.63 & 247.5 & 262.21 \\ \hline 
\textbf{P4} & 139.67 & 136.95 & 134.28 \\ \hline 
\textbf{P5} & 165.61 & 166.24 & 151.9 \\ \hline 
\textbf{P6} & 89.71 & 98.93 & 74.18 \\ \hline 
\textbf{Total Power Generation (MW)} & 1275.39 & 1275.51 & 1276.02 \\ \hline 
\textbf {Total Demand (MW)} & 1263 & 1263 & 1263 \\ \hline 
\textbf {Power Loss (MW)} & 12.39 & 12.51 & 13.02 \\ \hline 
\textbf {Total Generation Cost} & 15443 & 15448.72 & 15459 \\ \hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Here tried to give a different color in the first column by >{\columncolor{}} but the rowcolors{}{}{} always dominates the columncolor. Is there a way to replicate this MS Word table style?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion using `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \centering
\sisetup{table-format=5.2,
         group-minimum-digits=3}
    \caption{Caption}
\begin{tblr}{hlines=red!50, vlines=red!50,
             row{1}  = {guard,bg=cyan!50},
             row{odd[3]} = {bg=cyan!25},
             colspec = { Q[r,cyan!50] *{3}{S} },
             row{Z}  = {guard},
              }
Unit Power (MW) & {PSO}     & {MFO}     & {GA}      \\ 
P1              & 445.89    & 426.09    & 474.81    \\ 
P2              & 175.88    & 199.8     & 178.64    \\ 
P3              & 258.63    & 247.5     & 262.21    \\ 
P4              & 139.67    & 136.95    & 134.28    \\ 
P5              & 165.61    & 166.24    & 151.9     \\ 
P6              & 89.71     & 98.93     & 74.18     \\ 
Total Power Generation 
                & 1275.39   & 1275.51   & 1276.02   \\ 
Total Demand    & 1263      & 1263      & 1263      \\ 
Power Loss      & 12.39     & 12.51     & 13.02     \\ 
Total Generation Cost (\euro)  
                & 15443     & 15448.72  & 15459     \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You must be aware of the order of priority of `clortbl` package, so using `\rowcolors` the column color has no effect, but `\cellcolor` overrides to any other.

On the other hand:

1. Never ever place  a float in a center environment. Use `\centering` **inside** the float.
2. Use `tabulary` better than `tabularx` is you hava first column with more content that the others and you do not have the wrong manias of fit the table to the full text width or make all columns of the same width.
3. For numbers use `siunitx` for decimal allignement. If digits are very
   differen in every row (this case) the results is not very good anyway, but this is a problem of table design (bad businesses mix apples with oranges).
4. Colors of course are just a matter of personal taste. But take care of avoid colors patterns that people with daltonism cannot see.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, tabulary}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Caption}\extrarowheight1ex  
\rowcolors{1}{yellow!05}{green!10} 
\arrayrulecolor{green!50!red!30}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{|R|S[table-format=5.2]S[table-format=5.2]S[table-format=5.2]|} \hline 
\rowcolor{green!20}  Unit Power (MW) & {PSO} & {MFO} & {GA} \\ \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P1 & 445.89 & 426.09 & 474.81 \\ \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P2  & 175.88 & 199.8 & 178.64 \\\hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P3 & 258.63 & 247.5 & 262.21 \\\hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P4 & 139.67 & 136.95 & 134.28 \\  \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P5 & 165.61 & 166.24 & 151.9 \\\hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} P6 & 89.71 & 98.93 & 74.18 \\\hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} Total Power Generation & 1275.39 & 1275.51 & 1276.02 \\ \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} Total Demand & 1263 & 1263 & 1263 \\  \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} Power Loss & 12.39 & 12.51 & 13.02 \\  \hline 
\cellcolor{green!20} Total Generation Cost (\euro)  & 15443   & 15448.72 & 15459 \\\hline
\end{tabulary}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

A solution with `tabularray`:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % no more needed
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel} % 'french', 'german', 'spanish', 'danish', etc.
\usepackage[classicReIm]{kpfonts} % moved before txfonts otherwise it gives error
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{array, tabularx, blindtext}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[3]
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \begin{tblr}{
        width={0.51\textwidth},% 0.51 instead of 0.5 to avoid "Overfull \hbox" warning
        colspec={Q[c,m,2.4cm]*3{X[c]}}, vlines, hlines,
        row{odd} = {bg=cyan!50!gray!10},
        row{even} = {bg=gray!30!cyan!40},
        column{1}={bg={-red!75!green!80},font=\bfseries},
        row{1}={bg={-red!75!green!80},font=\bfseries},
        } 
        Unit Power (MW) & PSO & MFO & GA \\ 
        P1 & 445.89 & 426.09 & 474.81 \\  
        P2 & 175.88 & 199.8 & 178.64 \\ 
        P3 & 258.63 & 247.5 & 262.21 \\ 
        P4 & 139.67 & 136.95 & 134.28 \\ 
        P5 & 165.61 & 166.24 & 151.9 \\ 
        P6 & 89.71 & 98.93 & 74.18 \\ 
        Total Power Generation (MW) & 1275.39 & 1275.51 & 1276.02 \\  
        Total Demand (MW) & 1263 & 1263 & 1263\\
        Power Loss (MW) & 12.39 & 12.51 & 13.02 \\  
        Total Generation Cost & 15443 & 15448.72 & 15459 \\ 
    \end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

P.S. = don't put a table environment within a center environment, see  [When should we use \begin{center} instead of \centering?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is rather straightforward to get something like this with the `nice matrix` package, which neatly unifies the features of many table packages.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % 'cp1252'-Western, 'cp1251'-Cyrillic, etc.
\usepackage[a4paper, left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Colors with the \texttt{nicematrix} package.}
    \begin{NiceTabularX}{0.5\textwidth}{>{\centering\bfseries}m{2.4cm}|>{\centering}X|>{\centering}X|>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}[hvlines]
    \CodeBefore
        \rowcolors{2}{blue!30}{blue!20}
        \rectanglecolor{blue!80}{1-1}{11-1}
        \rectanglecolor{blue!80}{1-1}{1-4}
    \Body        
        Unit Power (MW) & \textbf{PSO} & \textbf{MFO} & \textbf{GA} \\ 
        P1 & 445.89 & 426.09 & 474.81 \\ 
        P2 & 175.88 & 199.8 & 178.64 \\ 
        P3 & 258.63 & 247.5 & 262.21 \\ 
        P4 & 139.67 & 136.95 & 134.28 \\
        P5 & 165.61 & 166.24 & 151.9 \\
        P6 & 89.71 & 98.93 & 74.18 \\
        Total Power Generation (MW) & 1275.39 & 1275.51 & 1276.02 \\ 
        Total Demand (MW) & 1263 & 1263 & 1263 \\ 
        Power Loss (MW) & 12.39 & 12.51 & 13.02 \\
        Total Generation Cost & 15443 & 15448.72 & 15459 \\ 
\end{NiceTabularX}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]