# too much space with centering inside a newcommand

Tags: macros, graphics, horizontal-alignment, formatting, center

I have created a newcommand to format titles in my prayer book. I want the newcommand to be centered, but with the following code, there is extra space above and below the newcommand. I tried to use `\centering` instead of `\begin{center}` `\end{center}`. but it doesn't compile centered.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
\begin{center}
    \noindent\large\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}\normalsize
\end{center}
}

\newcommand{\psalmheading}[1]{%
{\centering
    \noindent\large\bfseries\textcolor{red}{#1}\normalsize
}
}

\title{Test}
\author{Michael}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\prayerheading{Introductory Prayer}

In the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit. Amen.\\

Glory to Thee, our God, glory to Thee.\\

\prayerheading{Evening Troparia}

Have mercy on us, O Lord have mercy on us, for laying 
aside all excuse, we sinners offer to Thee as to our
Master this supplication: have mercy on us.\\

\psalmheading{Evening Troparia}

 Have mercy on us, O Lord have mercy on us, for laying 
 aside all excuse, we sinners offer to Thee as to our
 Master this supplication: have mercy on us.\\

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry I keep having issues having all the text that's in the code edited properly. So, I am trying to keep the look of the original code: `\prayerheading` but without the extra spacing above and below.

Thanks

Comment: use `\centering` but remove `\noindent` and replace `\normalsize` by `\par`

Comment: also never use `\\ ` at the end of paragraphs

Comment: Ok great thank you. So, using `\centering', remove `noindent' and use `\par' instead of  '\normalsize' is the better or more correct way to reduce spacing in new commands requiring centering?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23650/when-should-we-use-begincenter-instead-of-centering

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thank you for the link, that's the exact information I was wondering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(added `\medskip` and `\smallskip` directives to the definition of `\psalmheading` per the OP's request)

> So, I am trying to keep the look of the original code [for `\psalmheading`]: `\prayerheading` but without the extra spacing above and below.

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \large\bfseries\color{red}#1
  \end{center}
}

\newcommand{\psalmheading}[1]{%
   \begingroup
   \par\medskip%   <-- new: \medskip
   \centering\large\bfseries\color{red}#1
   \par\smallskip% <-- new: \smallskip
   \endgroup}

\begin{document}

\prayerheading{Introductory Prayer}

In the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit. Amen.

Glory to Thee, our God, glory to Thee.


\prayerheading{Evening Troparia}

Have mercy on us, O Lord have mercy on us, for laying aside all excuse, we sinners offer to Thee as to our Master this supplication: have mercy on us.

\psalmheading{Evening Troparia}

Have mercy on us, O Lord have mercy on us, for laying aside all excuse, we sinners offer to Thee as to our Master this supplication: have mercy on us.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Teepeemm - Thanks for pointing out that there was an issue with my code.

Comment: Is there a way to "add back" some of the space between the command and the next line, but not as much as I had with the initial MWE?

Comment: @Doc - Please be more specific as to what kind of "add back"  you have in mind.

Comment: The code provided in the answer above `\newcommand{\psalmheading}[1]{%
   \begingroup\par\centering\large\bfseries\color{red}#1\par \endgroup}'   The "heading" provided by the command `\psalmheading' now is directly above the following text, and while I am not wanting as much space as in my code `\newcommand{\prayerheading}[1]{%
  \begin{center}
    \large\bfseries\color{red}#1
  \end{center}}'    I do want some space maybe half as much as my code with the `\begin{center}' provdes.

Comment: @Doc - I've gone ahead and modified the definition of `\psalmheading` to (hopefully) meet your request. If the amount of additional whitespace still doesn't meet your requirements, please feel free to use `\bigskip` instead of `\medskip` and/or `\smallskip`.